# How to rotate image through onTouchListener?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to implement functionality to rotate image through onTouchListener(). Please provide me sample code to rotate image. Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code to rotate an image.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

baseView = (View) findViewById(R.id.baseView);
turntable = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.turntable);

turntable.setOnTouchListener(onTableTouched);
baseView.setOnTouchListener(onTableTouched);
```

}

```
public android.view.View.OnTouchListener onTableTouched = new android.view.View.OnTouchListener() {
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt) {
    double r = Math.atan2(evt.getX() - turntable.getWidth() / 2,
            (turntable.getHeight() / 2) - evt.getY());
    int rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);
    Log.i("R is ", ""+r);
    if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
    }

    if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
        x= evt.getX();
        y= evt.getY();
        updateRotation(rotation);
    }

    if (evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            //
    }
    return true;
}
};
private void updateRotation(double rot) {
float newRot = new Float(rot);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
R.drawable.orsl_circle_transparent);
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
//        matrix.setTranslate(getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth()/2,            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight());
    matrix.postRotate(newRot,bitmap.getWidth()/2,bitmap.getHeight()/2);
//      matrix.setSinCos(newRot, newRot/2, 100, 100);
//      matrix.postRotate(newRot);
    Log.i("THE ROATTION ", "  "+    newRot);

if(y>250)
{
    Bitmap redrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap
            .getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    turntable.setImageBitmap(redrawnBitmap);
}else
{
    Bitmap  redrawnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap
            .getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
     turntable.setImageBitmap(redrawnBitmap);
     Log.i("GUITAR _IMAGE", "");
}
}
```

Comment: In this code, image is rotating but also changing its position.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use an xml in type of "tween animation".
than, from the java code you can make a view act acording to this xml.
here is a link that help:
http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-beginner-tutorials/tween-animation/

Comment: Hi Roiberg, I want to rotate this image based on onTouch() direction. I have to use this rotating image to volume controller. So, have to implement this rotate through onTouch Listeners. If we use in xml file, onTouch controlls will not happen. Thanks for your reply.